# Where to redirect after inviting someone?

Tags: web-app, information-architecture, workflow, urls, redirect

We have 3 states for Users: **Active**, **Invited** and **Disabled**. Each user with the specific state is broken into a different tab. For example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQSozm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This shows the **Active** users list. When **Invited** is selected, only pending invitations are shown. And when **Disabled** is selected, only disabled users are shown.

The **Invite Users** button is visible on all 3 of the state tabs. When clicked, the user is taken to a form to enter one or many emails to invite:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI8Z5O.png)</sup>

When **Send Invitations** is clicked, the user is redirected to the **Invited** tab and shown a message:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe32Ns.png)</sup>

Is it correct to redirect to the **Invited** tab regardless of which tab they were originally on?

Or, should the user be redirected to their initial tab from which they clicked the **Invite Users** button (**Active**, **Invited** or **Disabled**)? Is the user their original context by being redirected to the **Invited** tab?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your decision to display the "invited" tab after the invitations are sent. Confirmation is huge aspect of UX that only gets noticed when it's not there. You've handled this using the dialogue box, but by showing the user the invited tab, you also inform them that they can check on the status of invitations in this view.

*However*, if the user is able to access this invitation button from another aspect of the site, then they should be returned to their original location upon completion (with the dialogue box).

Comment: Thanks. By "another aspect of the site", you're not referring to the **Active** or **Disabled** tabs are you?

Comment: No, I meant another page. Users may be confused if they don't return back to their original task.